# how to map keys for popup menu in vim

Tags: vim

After a completion try, omnicppcomplete will display all the possible items in the pop up menu . To select an certain item in the menu, one should use `<C-N>` and `<C-p>` to switch back and forth between different items. I feel that it is very inconvient . It should be very cool if  `j` and `k` can be used to to take place of `<C-N>` and `<C-P>` . so how should I do ?

Comment: just a suggestion. mapping j and k would disallow completing words with the j and k characters in them. you might want to use. ctrl-j and ctrl-k or similar instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function! OmniPopup(action)
    if pumvisible()
        if a:action == 'j'
            return "\<C-N>"
        elseif a:action == 'k'
            return "\<C-P>"
        endif
    endif
    return a:action
endfunction

inoremap <silent>j <C-R>=OmniPopup('j')<CR>
inoremap <silent>k <C-R>=OmniPopup('k')<CR>
```

Comment: It does work in my case. and this is my .vimrc file: https://github.com/xinfengwu/Notes_Vim/blob/master/configfiles/.my_vimrc
Located on line 364 - 376

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using the tab key for completion (I am not sure where I got this from):

```
"tab complete
function! InsertTabWrapper(direction)
    let col = col('.') - 1
    if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
        return "\<tab>"
    elseif "backward" == a:direction
        return "\<c-p>"
    else
        return "\<c-n>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper ("forward")<cr>
inoremap <s-tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper ("backward")<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL+J` and `CTRL+K` instead: (so you can type `j` and `k`)

```
inoremap <expr><C-J> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<C-J>"
inoremap <expr><C-K> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-K>"
```

Bonus: `<ENTER>` to select the option

```
inoremap <expr><Cr>  pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<Cr>"
```