# How to copy few lines of text from a vim editor to paste it somewhere on other editor?

Tags: vim, terminal, vim-plugin, gnome-terminal

I have started using vim editor from last 2 weeks and one problem the I face is I can't copy few bunch of codes to other editors or somewhere else however i can copy something to vim editor.

Below is my .vimrc file :-

```
" Automatic reloading of .vimrc
  autocmd! bufwritepost .vimrc source %


" Better copy & paste
" When you want to paste large blocks of code into vim, press F2 before you
" paste. At the bottom you should see ``-- INSERT (paste) --``.

  set pastetoggle=<F2>
  set clipboard=unnamed


" Mouse and backspace
  set mouse=a  " on OSX press ALT and click
  set bs=2     " make backspace behave like normal again


" Rebind <Leader> key
" I like to have it here becuase it is easier to reach than the default and
" it is next to ``m`` and ``n`` which I use for navigating between tabs.
  let mapleader = ","


" Bind nohl
" Removes highlight of your last search
" ``<C>`` stands for ``CTRL`` and therefore ``<C-n>`` stands for ``CTRL+n``
  noremap <C-n> :nohl<CR>
  vnoremap <C-n> :nohl<CR>
  inoremap <C-n> :nohl<CR>


" Quicksave command
  noremap <C-Z> :update<CR>
  vnoremap <C-Z> <C-C>:update<CR>
  inoremap <C-Z> <C-O>:update<CR>


" Quick quit command
  noremap <Leader>e :quit<CR>  " Quit current window
  noremap <Leader>E :qa!<CR>   " Quit all windows


" bind Ctrl+<movement> keys to move around the windows, instead of using Ctrl+w + <movement>
" Every unnecessary keystroke that can be saved is good for your health :)
  map <c-j> <c-w>j
  map <c-k> <c-w>k
  map <c-l> <c-w>l
  map <c-h> <c-w>h


" easier moving between tabs
  map <Leader>n <esc>:tabprevious<CR>
  map <Leader>m <esc>:tabnext<CR>


" map sort function to a key
  vnoremap <Leader>s :sort<CR>


" easier moving of code blocks
" Try to go into visual mode (v), thenselect several lines of code here and
" then press ``>`` several times.
  vnoremap < <gv  " better indentation
  vnoremap > >gv  " better indentation


" Show whitespace
" MUST be inserted BEFORE the colorscheme command
  autocmd ColorScheme * highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=red guibg=red
  au InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/


" Color scheme
" mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors && cd ~/.vim/colors
" wget -O wombat256mod.vim http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=13400
  set t_Co=256
  color wombat256mod


" Enable syntax highlighting
" You need to reload this file for the change to apply
  filetype off
  filetype plugin indent on
  syntax on


" Showing line numbers and length
  set number  " show line numbers
  set tw=79   " width of document (used by gd)
  set nowrap  " don't automatically wrap on load
  set fo-=t   " don't automatically wrap text when typing
  set colorcolumn=80
  highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=233


" easier formatting of paragraphs
  vmap Q gq
  nmap Q gqap


" Useful settings
  set history=700
  set undolevels=700


" Real programmers don't use TABs but spaces
  set tabstop=4
  set softtabstop=4
  set shiftwidth=4
  set shiftround
  set expandtab


" Make search case insensitive
  set hlsearch
  set incsearch
  set ignorecase
  set smartcase


" Disable stupid backup and swap files - they trigger too many events
" for file system watchers
  set nobackup
  set nowritebackup
  set noswapfile


" Setup Pathogen to manage your plugins
" mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle
" curl -so ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
" Now you can install any plugin into a .vim/bundle/plugin-name/ folder
  call pathogen#infect()


" ============================================================================
" Python IDE Setup
" ============================================================================


" Settings for vim-powerline
" cd ~/.vim/bundle
" git clone git://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline.git
  set laststatus=2


" Settings for ctrlp
" cd ~/.vim/bundle
" git clone https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git
  let g:ctrlp_max_height = 30
  set wildignore+=*.pyc
  set wildignore+=*_build/*
  set wildignore+=*/coverage/*


" Settings for python-mode
" Note: I'm no longer using this. Leave this commented out
" and uncomment the part about jedi-vim instead
" cd ~/.vim/bundle
" git clone https://github.com/klen/python-mode
"" map <Leader>g :call RopeGotoDefinition()<CR>
""let ropevim_enable_shortcuts = 1
""let g:pymode_rope_goto_def_newwin = "vnew"
""let g:pymode_rope_extended_complete = 1
""let g:pymode_breakpoint = 0
""let g:pymode_syntax = 1
""let g:pymode_syntax_builtin_objs = 0
""let g:pymode_syntax_builtin_funcs = 0
""map <Leader>b Oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() # BREAKPOINT<C-c>

" Settings for jedi-vim
" cd ~/.vim/bundle
""git clone git://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim.git
 let g:jedi#usages_command = "<leader>z"
 let g:jedi#popup_on_dot = 0
 let g:jedi#popup_select_first = 0
 map <Leader>b Oimport ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() # BREAKPOINT<C-c>

" Better navigating through omnicomplete option list
" See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170023/how-to-map-keys-for-popup-menu-in-vim
  set completeopt=longest,menuone
  function! OmniPopup(action)
      if pumvisible()
          if a:action == 'j'
              return "\<C-N>"
          elseif a:action == 'k'
              return "\<C-P>"
          endif
      endif
      return a:action
  endfunction

  inoremap <silent><C-j> <C-R>=OmniPopup('j')<CR>
  inoremap <silent><C-k> <C-R>=OmniPopup('k')<CR>


" Python folding
" mkdir -p ~/.vim/ftplugin
" wget -O ~/.vim/ftplugin/python_editing.vim http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=5492
  set nofoldenable
```

I added this to enable copy and paste things with use if `F2`

```
set pastetoggle=<F2>
  set clipboard=unnamed
```

I want to enable that feature. Please help
Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, Vim yanks (copies) to it's own internal register.
If you want to yank to a specific register, prepend your yank operation with a denotion of that register.
For example to yank a line to register x use

```
"xyy
```

To yank your visual selection to register z, use

```
"zy
```

The global clipboard is in register * or register + depending on your system

So to yank to one of these registers, replace x and z with * or +

Similarly, to put (paste) from the global clipboard, use

```
"*p
```

or

```
"+p
```